# Linux Mint sees Windows but update-grub won't update - possible corruption

Tags: linux-mint, grub, corruption

On dual boot machine, I suddenly could not boot into windows 10 and grub loader no longer was loading. I reinstalled Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia. Now I'm trying to add Windows to grub, which is on sda1.

When I run os-prober I get the following, which I think it means it sees Windows.

```
$ sudo os-prober
/dev/sda1:Windows 10:Windows:chain
```

But when I try to update grub, it says it cannot see sda. Update-grub just runs for ever.

fdisk says partition **does not start on physical sector boundary.**

```
Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *           63  315546477  315546415 150.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       315547648  317315071    1767424   863M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda3       318558206 1465147391 1146589186 546.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       318558208  709181439  390623232 186.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       709183488  719054847    9871360   4.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       719056896  859484159  140427264    67G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       859486208 1465147391  605661184 288.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I tried running ntfsfix

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... FAILED
Error: Failed to fix the alternate boot sector
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's what update-grub does:

```
$sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50_linuxmint.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/60_mint-theme.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/linuxmint/theme.txt
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
error: cannot read `/dev/sda': Input/output error.
```

Here's fdisk

Comment: Those errors indicate your `/dev/sda` disk is probably failing - and since the fault has affected GRUB and possibly the first partition, the fault is very likely at or near the beginning of the disk. **Make sure any important files anywhere on this disk are backed up. Right now.** If you cannot mount the `sda1` partition in Linux, use `ddrescue` to make a complete partition image of it to some other disk.That should make further recovery steps easier, assuming the `sda` disk already has unreadable sectors, as the error messages suggest.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I saved my files and put in an SSD hd